What are the theories on these titles concerning Rameses II?
In the pages 230-232 of "Rameses, Egypt Greatest Pharaoh", states Joice A. Tyldesley:

Group statues – statues showing Ramesses in association with one or more gods – were manufactured as objects of worship to be placed in the sanctuaries and side chapels of the major temples, thus firmly associating the mortal king with the worship of the divine gods.22 It is probably no accident that in many of the surviving examples the king is frequently better modelled, and more substantial, than his divine companions so that he effectively dominates the group. In many of the groups recovered from Pi-Ramesse the deity even bears Ramesses’ name, being labelled ‘X of Ramesses’, as in, for example, ‘Ptah of Ramesses’. This direct association of Ramesses and god is found at other Ramesside cities, so that at Memphis we again encounter ‘Ptah of Ramesses’, at Hermopolis ‘Thoth of Ramesses’ and at Karnak ‘Atum’, ‘Re’, ‘Amen’ and ‘Ptah of Ramesses’. These gods were worshipped alongside, rather than instead of, the more traditional Ptah, Amen, Atum and Re. The precise meaning of the phrase ‘of Ramesses’ is not obvious, although it might simply indicate that the god was a resident of or welcome visitor to Pi-Ramesse (Ramesses being used as an abbreviation of Pi-Ramesse) or indeed that Ramesses, rather than the temple, owned the figure? Art historians have suggested other, more subtle interpretations: did they allow Ramesses to merge his identity more firmly with that of the particular god shown? Or did they allow him to assume the more specific role of Re in his role of senior creator god (as Re had created the gods, so Ramesses created the statues of the gods) ? This identification of Ramesses with the sun god was extended further when, towards the end of his reign, he started to use the epithet ‘Great Soul of Re-Herakhty’, an epithet which was also added to the name of Pi-Ramesse.

Summary: Tyldesley is addressing a special kind of Ancient Egyptian deities that were associated with Rameses II through titles such as "Ra of Rameses" or "Ptah of Rameses" and so on. Among the theories about what these titles may actually mean, she mentions four:

These deities were considered residents or guests of Pi-Ramesse, the city of Ramesess II.
The figures were owned by Rameses II himself rather than by the temple.
Rameses II merged his identity more firmly with the mentioned deities.
Ramsess assumed the role of the creator of these deities.

For more details on the issue, she refers to the following sources in page 248:

22 The group statues of Ramesses and associated theories are discussed with references in Eaton-Krauss, M. (1991), ‘Ramesses – Re who creates the gods’, in Bleiberg, E. and Freed, R. (eds) Fragments of a Shattered Visage: The Proceedings of the International Symposium of Rameses the Great, Memphis: 15–23

Sadly I don't have access to any of these sources, or any other source on the issue.
My questions:
– What are these titles in Ancient Egyptian? I only need one example because I am interested in the pattern.
– What are all the theories made by Egyptologists on the meaning of those titles? What is the most academically accepted theory?
– Does this phenomena exist in regard to any other pharaohs, I mean, having statues of deity named after them in this particular pattern: "deity X of pharaoh Y" as if they were owned by the pharaoh? In case the answer is "yes", what does it mean according to Egyptologists?
Note: I actually asked this question here few days ago, but I deleted it on the same day since I felt like I needed to do a little more research. The deletion happened before receiving any answer, for sure.
====
Update: Joice A. Tyldesley definitely mentioned more than one example, but in English. Which shows that there is a pattern. Now I need to know the equivalent in the source language.

If you only have one example how can you tell there's a pattern or not?

An article in the The Journal of Egyptian Archaeology, Volume 5 from 1918 mentions Ptah of Ramesses as indication of a cult to Ptah within the city (Pi-Ramesses). It contains some references to associated hieroglyphs which may help answer the language/linguistics oriented portion of your query.

Eaton-Krauss (1991) is accessible via the Internet Archive.
